# asp:LoginView, Needs register link beside login

Tags: asp.net

I am using the asp login view and I get everything I need apart from a register link with the login link, I have tried to find the correct code for it with no luck.

Thanks

Comment: please see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184050.aspx

Comment: I am using web services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking for something like this?

```
<asp:LoginView ID="RegisterLink" runat="server">
  <AnonymousTemplate>
    <div class="titleRegistration">
      <a href="/Users/Register.aspx">Register</a> or 
    </div>
  </AnonymousTemplate>
  <LoggedInTemplate>
    <div class="titleRegistration">
      Welcome back
      <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" />
      -
    </div>
  </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
<asp:LoginStatus ID="lsGeneral" runat="server" LogoutPageUrl="/Users/Logout.aspx" />
```